# the same request works different in controller and helper (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, helper

i am facing a strange issue:

I have a table friendship:

```
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "friend_id"
```

I have 2 models: user.rb and friendship.rb

friendship.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

User.rb:

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

Why if I use **user.inverse_friends** gives me different data in friendship controller and in friendship helper? I would be grateful if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Are you saying **user.friendships** and **user.inverse_friendships**,  **user.inverse_friends** and **user.friends** gives you different results?

Comment: exactly, depend on the data in the friendship table

Comment: Can you check if the **user** object used in controller and helper are same by giving **user.inspect** in logger

Comment: I have to ask - what the heck are `inverse_friends`? 00 Do you want to implement symmetrical association? Or do you really think of having an option to be a friend with someone for whom you are not a friend?

Comment: @Abhi yes, this is the same object. actually I use there current_user which is the same anywhere.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some sample output of the four associations (`user.friendships, user.inverse_friendships, user.inverse_friends and user.friends`)

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, for example there are user1 and user2. User1 adds user2 to friends, so a new record in friendship table is added: user1 | user2. to complete the friendship, user 2 should accept user1 request, so another record will appear user2 | user1. I there are 2 records for a pair of user1 and user2 that means that friendship is accepted. If there is only one record, then only requested. And the problem is that in the controller user.friends and user.inverse_friends are differens, but if I request the same in helper, user.inverse_friends shows me the same like it was user_friends

Comment: for example: user.friends: [#<User id: 2, name: "neon_20", email: "20@mail.ru", created_at: "2015-06-06 15:48:55", updated_at: "2015-06-06 16:10:14", password_digest: "$2a$10$W/owxaD8PSTXRRewsdLS4uLujQFNQQRT.eyR7Tp/LPe...", remember_token: "a7075d5ea1cfb50b824ff02a513bf0e371a9d569", avatar_file_name: "DSC_6101.jpg", avatar_content_type: "image/jpeg", avatar_file_size: 3859807, avatar_updated_at: "2015-06-06 15:48:52">]>

Comment: user.inverse_friends: []> (there are no requests from other users)

Comment: user.friendships: [#<Friendship id: 9, user_id: 3, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2015-06-06 16:29:02", updated_at: "2015-06-06 16:29:02">]>

Comment: user.inverse_friendships: []> (empty, there are no friendships requested)

Comment: The last suggestion I can give you is to look at the logs and check what are the queries fired for **user.friendships** & **user.inverse_friendships** respectively. That may give you a pick.

Comment: @Abhi no, i can not explain why it works like that.. if the code executes in the controller it produces the same queries as when it is in the helper, but result is different.. Look, I have paired the requests: (1 - user.friends, 2 - user.reverse_friends):

Comment: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 3]]

Comment: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."user_id" WHERE "friendships"."friend_id" = $1  [["friend_id", 3]]
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."user_id" WHERE "friendships"."friend_id" = $1  [["friend_id", 3]]

Comment: they are the same...

Comment: Check carefully, the inner joins are on different columns in both queries, eg:- **"users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id"** in first query and **"users"."id" = "friendships"."user_id"** on second. This is enough to change the output